# Retrieve days from System.currentTimeMillis() - bug

Tags: scala

I tried to retrieve a certain number of days from the current date; it works until 24 days but for 25 days it add days instead of retrieving ...

Does anyone of you understand why?

```
import java.sql.Timestamp

val retrieve_days: ((Int) => java.sql.Timestamp) = (nb_days: Int) => {
    new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()- nb_days*24*60*60*1000)
} 

val today = retrieve_days(0)
// today: java.sql.Timestamp = 2019-03-01 15:43:41.418

val minus1d = retrieve_days(1)
// minus1d: java.sql.Timestamp = 2019-02-28 15:43:41.958

val minus10d = retrieve_days(10)
// minus10d: java.sql.Timestamp = 2019-02-19 15:43:42.502

val minus20d = retrieve_days(20)
// minus20d: java.sql.Timestamp = 2019-02-09 15:43:42.895

val minus23d = retrieve_days(23)
//minus23d: java.sql.Timestamp = 2019-02-06 15:43:43.245

val minus24d = retrieve_days(24)
//minus24d: java.sql.Timestamp = 2019-02-05 15:43:43.577

val minus25d = retrieve_days(25)
//minus25d: java.sql.Timestamp = 2019-03-26 08:46:31.817
```

Thank you!

Comment: As a general rule it is better to use a date/time library when dealing with longer time periods, as it will deal with range issues and other oddities (e.g. leap seconds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculation for `25` days is too large for the `Int` type:

```
25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 
// mathematical value is 2160000000

Int.MaxValue
// 2147483647

// we can see the calculation is larger, this is why it becomes negative, therefore *adding* more time.
```

What you can do to remedy this is change it to a `Long` to get the appropriate calculation, this can be done by adding a `.toLong` at the appropriate place:

```
val retrieve_days: Int => java.sql.Timestamp = (nb_days: Int) => {
    new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()- nb_days.toLong*24*60*60*1000)
} 

val minus25d = retrieve_days(25)
// minus25d: java.sql.Timestamp = 2019-02-04 10:09:48.613
```

Comment: Thank you for the explaination and for the solution! :-)